# Java read string as byte[]

Tags: java, utf-8

I want to convert a series of bytes in a byte[] to a string to append to a text file. Then when the string is pulled I want to convert it back to byte[] to decode it. I know I can't use `getBytes()`, I need to copy the string to it's original byte[] format then decode it back to a readable string. Is this possible?

```
     byte[] hash = pw.getBytes("UTF8");
     pw = hash.toString();
```

Then I pass the string to another class where I need it to be read as bytes, not changed to its byte form.

Answer (score 3):

`toString` won't work. You need to write, because that is the string representation of Array Object.

```
String s = new String(hash,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: So this is the correct way to turn the byte[] in to a String. How do I convert the String back in to bytes?

Comment: @caine1337: Exactly the way you did it in your original question, with `pw.getBytes("UTF-8")`.  You've _already done_ that correctly.

Comment: @caine1337  `byte[] hash = pw.getBytes("UTF8");` where pw is a string.

Comment: Down votes, when helping ?? Great.

Comment: So the series of encoded characters in my String will be read by getBytes the same way that the original String would?